# response header set in action disappears in view - asp net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, http-headers

In a controller action, response header is set like this:

```
HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("key", "value");
```

In rendered view, Response.Headers["key"] seems to be null (btw in ajax requests, header is set and retrieved without any problems). Is there any special reason for this or is this a silly bug in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only add response headers but you cannot read them unless you are running in IIS 7 integrated pipeline mode. When running in standard model HTTP response headers are sent at a later stage by the time you try to read them in your code. This has been stated in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.headers.aspx):

> The Headers property is only supported with the IIS 7.0 integrated
>   pipeline mode and at least the .NET Framework 3.0. When you try to
>   access the Headers property and either of these two conditions is not
>   met, a PlatformNotSupportedException is thrown.

This being said, all that a view should access is a view model, not response headers. So in your controller action you will build a view model containing all the information that the view will require and pass it to the view for consumption. Remember: a view doesn't pull data, a view uses data that it is being handled from the controller under the form of a view model.

Comment: You can also stash the data in the ViewBag. It doesn't need to go in the view model.

Comment: @RickAnderson-MSFT, no, for me ViewData is crap. I never use it. It is weakly typed, it relies on magic strings, it cannot enforce compile-time safety, the views become very ugly because in order to access the actual properties you need to cast it, ... So *stashing* something into ViewBag for me is like throwing this something into the dustbin. ViewBag/ViewCarp. View models is the only way to do ASP.NET MVC for me. Sorry for the rant but its my personal opinion and way to do things.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are trying to pass some data from your controller to your view. If that is the case, you should use ViewData or ViewBag instead.

In your Controller:

```
ViewData["key"] = "value";
```

In your View

```
<span>Your key: @ViewData["key"]</span>
```

Comment: For MVC 3+, use ViewBag in lieu of ViewData["key"=